# How tall would a Warhammer 40k Wraithknight be if it were real?

Tags: warhammer-40k, mecha

I have used Google quite a bit to try and find this answer.  I've tried to scale the 9" model metric with some sort of consistency, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea how big these bad boys can get?

Comment: [Pretty tall](https://1d4chan.org/images/8/85/Wraithknight.jpg)

Comment: Comparison of the models alone suggests that a Wraithknight is roughly 6-7 times as tall as your average Eldar troop, who are themselves taller than a man. If we said that your average Eldar troop is 7 feet tall, then we can say with some confidence that the Wraithknight is somewhere between 42-49 feet tall, likely around 44 feet tall, which (surprise, surprise) is exactly the height Paul gave in their answer. Personally, I think their very accurate "estimate" is right on the money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nominally, 40k miniatures are supposed to be about 28mm scale, or 1/58. http://www.librarium-online.com/forums/hobby-forums/29275-what-scale-warhammer.html#/topics/29275?_k=le2qav

They are not always consistent, but that should at least give you a ballpark that a 9" model would be about 43' 6" tall (9 x 58 12)